# Универсальная AJAX-функция

Tags: javascript, ajax

Нужна функция function getAjax(url,params), которая принимала бы аргументы: url(url get-запроса), массив данных params и возвращала бы массив или объект или строку response сервера:

```
var url="/site/ajax";
var params=["phone","title","price"];
data=getAjax(url,params);
alert(data);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const getAjax = (method, url, params) => {
    let data;
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    let json = JSON.stringify(params);

    xhr.open(method, url, true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
    xhr.send(json);

    xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
        if (xhr.readyState != 4) return;

        func(JSON.parse(xhr.responseText));
    }
};

const func = (callback) => {
    let data = callback;
    console.log(data);
}

getAjax(method, url, params);
```

Comment: Этот код всегда будет выводить в консоль `undefined`. Есть сомнения, что это именно то, что требуется автору вопроса :)

Comment: Почему оно всегда будет выводить undefined? Будет undef, только если сервер не сможет обработать запрос

Comment: @Рустам Гимранов, спасибо, вроде исправил))

Comment: @Рустам Гимранов, я так обычно и делаю. Просто не было под рукой сервера, а заменить сервер на setTimeout только сейчас додумался) Но всё равно учту